# I can't understand result in my textbook.

Tags: physics

I've the following equation in my physics text book:
given that 
$$t=t_1+t_2+t_3,$$$$t_2=t_3$$ $$s_1 = v_1t_1,$$ $$s_2 =v_2t_2;$$ $$s_3 = v_3t_3,$$$$s_2+s_3=\frac{s}{2}=s_1$$
$$t= t_1 + 2t_2 \implies t_2=\frac{t-t_1}{2}.$$ From here starts the part that I don't understand:
$$s_1=\frac{s}{2}=s_2+s_3= v_2t_2+v_3t_3=(v_2+v_3)\frac{t-t_1}{2}=v_1t_1$$
from here they jump to:
$$t=\frac{(2v_1+v_2+v_3)t_1}{v_2+v_3}$$
I don't understand how they made this transition, I'm skipping some little detail and I can't find it.Any hits which will make it easier ?

Comment: Right before the jump, take the last equality (the last pair of equal expressions) and solve for $t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the last two parts to the chain equality and divide both sides by $(v_2+v_3)/2$ to get
$$t-t_1=\frac{2v_1t_1}{v_2+v_3}$$ then adding $t_1$ to both sides gives $$t=\left(\frac{2v_1}{v_2+v_3}+1\right)t_1$$

Now just simplify the term in parens by changing the $1$ to $\frac{v_2+v_3}{v_2+v_3}$

Answer (score 0):

$$
(v_2+v_3)\frac{t-t_1}{2}=v_1t_1 \iff (v_2+v_3)(t-t_1)=2v_1t_1
$$
that, using distributivity, gives
$$
 (v_2+v_3)t-(v_2+v_3)t_1=2v_1t_1 \iff(v_2+v_3)t=2v_1t_1+(v_2+v_3)t_1
$$

can you do from this?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(v_2+v_3)\frac{t-t_1}{2}=v_1 t_1$$
This can be written as:
$$(v_2+v_3)(t-t_1)=2v_1 t_1$$
Now, we can expand:
$$v_2 t-v_2 t_1+v_3 t-v_3 t_1=2v_1t_1$$
And factorise:
$$t(v_2+v_3)-t_1(v_2+v_3)=2v_1 t_1$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with $$(v_2+v_3)\frac{t-t_1}{2}=v_1t_1\ ...$$

\begin{align}
(v_2+v_3)\frac{t-t_1}{2}&=v_1t_1\\
t(v_2+v_3)-t_1(v_2+v_3)&=2v_1t_1 & \text{Multiply by 2 and distribute on LHS}\\
t(v_2+v_3)&=t_1(v_2+v_3)+2v_1t_1 & \text{Move $t_1(v_2+v_3)$ to RHS}\\
t(v_2+v_3)&=t_1(2v_1+v_2+v_3) & \text{Factor $t_1$ from RHS}\\
t&=\frac{t_1(2v_1+v_2+v_3)}{v_2+v_3} & \text{Divide by $v_2+v_3$}
\end{align}